# Why does this two static constexpr int variable behave "differently"?

Tags: c++

English is not my first language.Please forgive my syntax mistake.

I am new to mutiThread programming, and I am doing a mutiThread Lab about spinLock. A couple of **constexpr type** variable's behaviour really occur my concerning. Here is the code.

(P.S. The WriteUp of the Lab provides a Lock Class and it work fine, everything is good.)

```
class spin_lock
{
    static constexpr int UNLOCKED = 1;

    static constexpr int LOCKED = 0;

    std::atomic<int> m_value{1};

public:
    void lock()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            int expected = UNLOCKED;
            if (m_value.compare_exchange_strong(expected, LOCKED)) // watch out for this line
                break;
        }
    }
```

there are two Thread son and dad, son is consumer and dad is producer:

```
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <iostream>
#include <atomic>

static std::atomic<int> orangeNum(0);
static std::atomic<int> appleNum(0);
static constexpr int FULL = 1;
static constexpr int EMPTY = 0;

void * son(void * arg) {
    while(true){
        myLock.lock();
        std::cout<<"plant locked by son"<<std::endl;
        if(orangeNum.compare_exchange_strong(FULL,EMPTY) && appleNum.compare_exchange_strong(EMPTY,EMPTY)){
            std::cout<<"son take out orange."<<std::endl;
            myLock.unlock();
            std::cout<<"plant unlocked by son"<<std::endl;
            continue;
        } else {
            std::cout << "son cannot take out orange." << std::endl;
            myLock.unlock();
            std::cout << "plant unlocked by son" << std::endl;
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

I am using Clion on Arch linux with `g++ (GCC) 11.2.0`

IDE mark red underline looked like this(with error notice, error:No matching member function for call to 'compare_exchange_strong').
[image]

if I delete `constexpr` in declaration of `static constexpr int FULL = 1; static constexpr int EMPTY = 0;`.Every thing goes fine.
[image]

while the spin_lock class work fine with `constexpr`:
[image]

the whoal code file is looked like this.

```
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <iostream>
#include <atomic>


static std::atomic<int> orangeNum(0);
static std::atomic<int> appleNum(0);

static constexpr int FULL = 1;//error
static constexpr int EMPTY = 0;//error

//static int FULL = 1;//good
//static int EMPTY = 0;//good

class spin_lock
{
    static constexpr int UNLOCKED = 1;

    static constexpr int LOCKED = 0;

    std::atomic<int> m_value{1};

public:
    void lock()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            int expected = UNLOCKED;
            if (m_value.compare_exchange_strong(expected, LOCKED))
                break;
        }
    }

    void unlock()
    {
        m_value.store(UNLOCKED);
    }
};
static spin_lock myLock;
void * son(void * arg) {
    while(true){
        myLock.lock();
        std::cout<<"plant locked by son"<<std::endl;
        if(orangeNum.compare_exchange_strong(FULL,EMPTY) && appleNum.compare_exchange_strong(EMPTY,EMPTY)){
            std::cout<<"son take out orange."<<std::endl;
            myLock.unlock();
            std::cout<<"plant unlocked by son"<<std::endl;
            continue;
        } else {
            std::cout << "son cannot take out orange." << std::endl;
            myLock.unlock();
            std::cout << "plant unlocked by son" << std::endl;
            continue;
        }
    }
}

void * dad(void * arg){
//quite similar to son.
}

int main(){
    pthread_t dadThread, sonThread;
    int ret;

    ret=pthread_create(&dadThread,nullptr, dad,0);
    ret=pthread_create(&sonThread,nullptr, son,0);




    pthread_join(dadThread,NULL);
    pthread_join(sonThread,NULL);


}
```

why these constexpr type behave differently?

Comment: Are you sure your `spin_lock` works fine with `constexpr`?

Comment: Take a better look at what arguments does `compare_exchange_strong` expect: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/compare_exchange. It takes a `T&`

Comment: Don't put too much trust in those "live" checking features – they are just approximations. What matters is whether the code compiles.

Comment: @molbdnilo I would be surprised if that code ever compiles. Look what **theWiseBro** has sent.

Comment: Apart from  @theWiseBro's comment, why `pthread`s? You'd better try C++11 `std::thread` or even better `std:: jthread` with C++20 support.

Answer (score 1):

I'm the original poster.

I have checked the solutions and tips in comment and now I have learnt what is wrong I've done.

first of all, I just copy the lock class and didn't notice that this line

```
int expected = UNLOCKED;
```

The `expected` is of type `int` - not `const int`.

Secondly, the type of the first arg of `compare_exchange_strong()` is lvalue reference.So it can't bind to a non-modified-able lvalue which is a const static lvalue in this case.

Thirdly, the manual book I referred to is too old, thanks you guys for introducing `std::jthread` for me[here is some doc about it](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/jthread).

Thanks very much~!

Comment: BTW (as additional info): `jthread` stands for 'joining thread'; nothing to do with https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html

Comment: The reason why the first argument to `compare_exchange_strong()` can't be `const` is that on failure it is updated to the current value.